# Rigorous proof for a trivial set-theoretic property

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the following property:

$$\lbrace x | x \in \cup_{n}W_n \rbrace = \cup_{n} \lbrace x | x \in W_n \rbrace.$$

How would one prove this property from first principles in a rigorous way? Is it anything more than an English argument invoking the ZCF axiom of extensionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows trivially from the fact, for any set $S$,

$$ S = \{ s \mid s \in S \} $$